# Silex2: Security firewall and locale

Tags: symfony, silex

How do I add the current locale to paths like /user/login or /user/logout? Controllers do support the '{_locale}' placeholder, but within the security  pattern it is reported as an error.

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/user/login$',
    ),
    'secured_area' => array(
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'anonymous' => false,
        'remember_me' => array(),
        'form' => array(
           'login_path' => '/user/login',
           'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
        ),
       'logout' => array(
           'logout_path' => '/user/logout',
           'invalidate_session' => true,
       ),
    ),
 );
```

Comment: probably you need to fix your routes like this http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#translation-locale-url

Comment: The security component does not work with the *_locale* placeholder. But it can work with named routes, [check this out](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/1276)

Comment: @mTorres: I don't see any 'named route' solution in this link. There's a session workaround only and someone mentions named routes, but he doesn't explain how named routes can solve the security pattern problem.

Comment: @sakhunzai: The routes are already working, thanks to the magic {_locale} placeholder. The problem is the security component and the redirect to the localized login path.

Comment: As I understand it, you have to register the login_path, check_path and  logout_path yourself instead of [relaying on the SecurityServiceProvider](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L681). You have to [name these routes](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/usage.html#named-routes) (like ```$app->match('/{_locale}/user/login', ...)->bind('login')``` and then on your security configuration use the route name instead of the route path (```login_path``` => 'login'). I haven't tried this myself, so I'm just pointing to a possible solution...

Comment: @mTorres: Many thanks, it works now!

Comment: You should post your working code (as an answer) then, if anyone has the same problem your solution might work for them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the route name (controller bind) in 'login_path', not the full path.

```
$app->get('/{_locale}/user/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
    ));
})->bind('login');


$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/(de|en|fr|es)/user/login$',
    ),
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'anonymous' => false,
        'remember_me' => array(),
        'form' => array(
        'login_path' => 'login',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
        'post_only' => true,
        'with_csrf' => true,
        'default_target_path' => 'homepage'
    ),
    'logout' => array(
        'logout_path' => '/user/logout',
        'invalidate_session' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem but I have trouble with my `/login_check` : when I have my default locale set up it's ok (my url look like this `/url`) but when I change my langage (my url look like this `/locale/url`) it doesn't works. My login page is ok when I try to connect it works if my url is `/login` but not when it's `/locale/login`, I have a 404 error on page `/locale/login-check`...any idea?

Comment: The "check_path" (login form action) doesn't need a locale.

Comment: I made a question to explain my problem, if you have some time : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236815/silex-2-security-firewall-error-with-locale-silex-securityserviceprovider-p